# gitlab pg_dump version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I just recently transfered a gitlab instance to a new server. I thought everything was fine until I went to apt upgrade and the backup failed.

```
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlab ... pg_dump: server version: 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4); pg_dump version: 11.7
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

system info
It is connected to postgresql db on the system and not the gitlab-builtin bundled version

this is also gitlab's bionic repo despite the system being focal because it seems they dont actually have focal support quite ready at this time. (packages missing)

```
System information
System:         Ubuntu 20.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.6.6p146
Gem Version:    2.7.10
Bundler Version:1.17.3
Rake Version:   12.3.3
Redis Version:  5.0.9
Git Version:    2.27.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.7
Go Version:     unknown

GitLab information
Version:        13.1.4
Revision:       18c5ab32b73
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     12.2
```

where is this 11.7 coming from? What do I do to resolve this?
a `pg_dump --version` returns `pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4)`. This is a fresh server install and has never had other pgsql servers installed.

bonus question: do i need to care about `Go Version:     unknown`? It's the same on the old server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab was using a packaged version of pg_dump. After finding it out from [GitLab - Database - Backup and restore a non-packaged PostgreSQL database](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/database.md#backup-and-restore-a-non-packaged-postgresql-database)

running this solved the issue

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/psql /opt/gitlab/bin/
```